# Problema con "comillas" y Paths en un script en CMD (Batch), pasando argumentos a un EXE

Tags: c++, cmd, batch

Me está pasando algo muy raro con este script. Por algún motivo la variable %PTH% está dando problemas con las comillas, y por culpa de esto no se pueden usar PATHs que contengan espacios.

```
@echo off
set CurrDir=%cd%
set BatchFileDir=%~dp0

REM UTF-8
chcp 65001

goto :main

:GetFileData
for /R %CurrDir% %%i in (*.*) do (  
    Echo Procesando el archivo: "%%i" & set fname=%%~ni 
    set FullFilePath=%%i
    set curr_pth=%%~dpi
    set EXTENSION=%%~xi
    ) & call :renombrar     
goto :eof


:renombrar 
set  "PTH=%curr_pth%"    
set  "FN=%fname:~0,-1%"
set  "EXE=%BatchFileDir%renombrar.exe"
CALL "%EXE%"  %PTH%  "%FN%"  "%EXTENSION%" "%PTH%%FN%%EXTENSION%"
goto :eof


:main
call :GetFileData
goto :eof
```

Si lo ejecuto así no hay problema siempre que el PATH no tenga espacios. El .exe le entran estos parametros:

```
Path     --> argv[1] -->C:\Carpeta1\Carpeta1\Carpeta3\
FileName --> argv[2] -->Nombre del archivo
Extension--> argv[3] -->.extensión
FullPath --> argv[4] -->C:\Carpeta1\Carpeta1\Carpeta3\Nombre del archivo.extensión
```

EL problema aparece si pongo la variable "%PTH%" entre comillas, lo cual me gustaría para poder usar rutas que contengan espacios. En ese caso tengo esta salida en el EXE.

```
Path     --> argv[1] -->C:\Carpeta1\Carpeta1\Carpeta3\" Nombre
FileName --> argv[2] -->del
Extension--> argv[3] -->archivo
FullPath --> argv[4] -->.extensión
```

**El problema no está en el código C++.** Esto es lo único que tengo de momento funcionando en el EXE.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Path     --> argv[1] -->" << argv[1] <<  endl;
    cout << "FileName --> argv[2] -->" << argv[2] <<  endl;
    cout << "Extension--> argv[3] -->" << argv[3] <<  endl;
    cout << "FullPath --> argv[4] -->" << argv[4] <<  endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

No logro ver donde puede estar el fallo. ¿Alguna ídea?

Comment: Solo por curiosidad. ¿ Has intentado, desde el `.exe`, interpretar **toda** la línea de comandos y no solo los 4 primeros ? A ver que obtienes si la ruta tiene espacios.

Comment: No lo he hecho, pero sé lo que se obtendria... cada palabra separado por espacios entraría como si fuera un argumento, hasta llegar a argv[argc]=NULL

Comment: ¿ Y no te vale con eso ?

Comment: Hombre... No lo creo, hacerlo así sería un dolor de cabeza... esto está diseñado para ahorrarte ese dolor de cabeza y lo único que hay que hacer es poner todo lo que tenga espacios entre comillas para que lo entienda como si fuera un único argumento.

Comment: Pues entonces, ya puedes quitar toda la parte C++ de la pregunta, que lo único que hace es distraer ;-)

Comment: Si lo puse precisamente para que vieran que el problema no está en el código en C++ sino en el script de CMD :-) .... bueno como veo que confunde voy a comentarlo ahi arriba